# How to add new python packages to existing Docker image?

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm following throught the Compose tutorial on Django:

https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

It uses a `requirements.txt` file to define Python packages and then builds the image and creates a Django project:

`sudo docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .`

I noticed that after adding another dependency to requirements, I couldn't issue the `docker-compose run web` command again without receiving this error:

```
CommandError: /code/manage.py already exists. Overlaying a project into an existing directory won't 
replace conflicting files.
```

What is the correct way of rebuilding the image after having added new dependencies?

Comment: The command line you gave is unrelated to the dependencies. It creates the project's folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you continue learning about [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and [docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) generally. If you want to add the new package all you need is to add it in the `requirements.txt` file and then you run [docker-compose build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) so that the packages will be installed and any other new service (that was recently added in your docker-compose.yml file)  will be built. I assume you have the `Dockerfile` of course. To run the dockerized application all you need to do is run `docker-compose up`. A practical example here [Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn, and Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/).